# Multiple Master-Details with root view - iOS

Tags: ios, master-detail, uistoryboardsegue, rootview

I have a master-detail application. The master scene is a tableview and the detail is a simple view controller with some text.

I'd like however to have more than one master-detail (one for every topic), and a homepage, with images / buttons. When I click on one of them, I want to get transferred to the corresponding master-detail.

I added a view controller to the story board (call it A), changed the root view to A, added a button in A and added a push segue from that button to the master scene (ctrl+drag). But this does not seem to work when I run it.

Any ideas? Thank you

I figured it out - I was using

```
UINavigationController * navController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;

MasterViewController * masterController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

and the object at index 0 was no longer the master view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have multiple "master-detail" you will need to push controllers from both sides using `UINavigationControllers`. First make sure that your A controller is inside a navigation controller, and if it is but still not working, then check the storyboard because there's probably some error or something not linked

Comment: Initially, I have a navigation controller, with a relationship segue (root view controller) to the master view controller, and there is a push segue from master to detail. I want the homepage to come before the master. And I want to have many master details.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be better to use a UITabBarController as the root view controller. The first tab can contain your home page controller, and the other tabs would contain UINavigationControllers with master controllers as their root view controllers.